# Does windowsphone 8 keep the unused IsolatedStorage in case of application updating?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

After Updating A windows phone 8 app, will it keep the unused IsolatedStorage?
and if i change object saved in it, will it throw exceptions on users devices because of object changes doesn't saved under the key saved in the old version.

if so, how can i change/remove Edited/Unused IsolatedStorageSettings when i update a windows phone 8 application?

Answer (score 0):

`Isolated Storage` data are preserved between updates, so it's the same `IsolatedStorageSettings` as in old version.

If you add/change objects in this way: `settings["key"] = value;` nothing wrong will happens after update. Also, you can check if some value exists or not before read it:

```
if (settings.Contains("key"))
{
    string value = (string) settings["key"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, But, First: If I Have data in Isolated Storage and i wont use it anymore in the next version. what happen to it?

Comment: It will still be there but you can look to see if the file exists on app start and delete it if not needed

Comment: Second: if I Put all my Settings Variable in object and save it to Isolated storage. Like in this Link: [link](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-store-data-in-isolatedstoragesettings) if in the next update i change the object saved in isolated storage to have more variables, will it throw exception because i didn't save it again with its changes because of using `if (settings.Contains("key"))`and its already contain the key but with object of another structure.

Comment: @Ken Tucker Any links For how to see if the file exists on app start and delete it if not needed especially if i don't know key of data stored?

Comment: IsolatedStorageSettings has a keys property you can use to get all the stored settings names.  Loop though the settings and delete the ones you do not need.  You can delete a IsolatedStorageSetting with the remove method.

Comment: under what condition, i only need it for one time after update.

Comment: and what do You think about the second Question of Changing in object under the same key, Thank You @KenTucker

Comment: There nothing wrong with changing what is stored in the setting just make sure your code can handle any data types changing.   As for removing the old settings that is up to you.  I typically remove a setting if it is not needed anymore